# Jquery Not working in onchange function (Play scala view page and Ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scala

I have the following Jquery code on play Scala view page with script tag But **if and else if** statement not working already I search it, But my condition is different (I have session value is "ADC")

```
    $('#sampleId').on('change', function(){

        var x = document.getElementById("sampleId").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("cId").value;


            $.ajax({

                url:"/sampleApp?sampleId="+x+"&cId="+y,

                success:function(result){
                    $.map(result,function(obj, i){

                    var status = obj.values

                   if('@role' == "ADC" && '+ status +' == "Applied" || "Verified"){  

                      alert("Hi...");
                      @println("Im....In")

                } else if('@role' == "ADC" && '+ status +' == "Approved" || "Admitted"){

                       alert("Bye...");
                       @println("Im....Else")
        }
            });
      }

     });
    });
```

Output:

```
Im....In
Im....Else
```

If i will any changes in my code?

Comment: Problem with `if else` condition.. Try with `'+ status +' == "Approved" || '+ status +' == "Admitted"`

Comment: I try this way but no use - @GuruprasadRao

Comment: @udayakumarb I just noticed that you also have this loop: `$.map(result,function(obj, i){`. What is this meant to do? I am sorry but you will need to clarify and expand your question because right now it is impossible to find out what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` conditions look completely mangled. This for instance...

```
if('@role' == "ADC" && '+ status +' == "Applied" || "Verified")
```

...looks nonsensical. This statement will be true every time because of that last OR condition. It looks like you are doing that most classic of beginner mistakes when you want to check if a variable is one value or another.

The **wrong** way to do it.

```
if (myVariable == 'foo' || 'bar')
```

The **right** way to do it.

```
if (myVariable == 'foo' || myVariable == 'bar')
```

Also I cannot figure out what you are trying to do. This, for instance,...

```
'@role' == "ADC"
```

...seems to query if the literal string `@role` is equal to the literal string `ADC`.

My answer to you is to completely revise your `if` statements because 1) they are unreadable and 2) they are wrong, for reasons mentioned above.

My best guess is that your if-statement should look something like this (assuming that @role is some Scala specific substitution:

```
if("@role" == "ADC" && (status == "Applied" || status == "Verified")) {
   ...
} else if("@role" == "ADC" && (status == "Approved" || status == "Admitted")) {
```

Comment: yeah.. I try this way but again return the same output.. @Michael Karnerfors

Comment: @udayakumarb See the edits I made. I am *assuming* that "@role" is some Scala specific substitution that is made. If not, then that bit is definitely wrong too.

Answer (score 0):

Just I change  **'+ status +' to status**, the code is working fine,

```
if('@role' == "ADC" && status  == "Applied" || status  == "Verified"){  

                          alert("Hi...");
                          @println("Im....In")

                    } else if('@role' == "ADC" && status  == "Approved" || status  == "Admitted"){

                           alert("Bye...");
                           @println("Im....Else")
            }
```

Thanks to all...

Comment: Just to point out that your if-statements may still contain an error. Remember that AND takes precedence over OR. So these if-conditions will render `true` if `status == "Verified"` even if @role is **not** `"ADC"`